# Mixed content from my staging server

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to deploy my updated website. But when I move my files over, my website is no longer in "Secured" due to mixed content.

The mixed content is the website trying to call images from my development server

instead of saying: `https://www.website.com/image1`

It brings up `/IP ADDRESS of dev server/image1`

Since my dev server is not for the public, it does not have SSL on it. But I'm not sure why its bringing up files from my development server now that i'm on the production server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good chance you have either:

1. Not updated your base URL correctly
2. Hard coded Dev URLs

If using Chrome, use an Inspect Element to identify references to your Dev URL and then double check the source code to ensure it isn't hard-coded.

If you have access to phpMyAdmin (or similar), do a database search for your old URL.

Oh, and as usual, make sure you clear your /var/cache folder cause the number one pain of my life has always been caching in Magento.

Hope this helps in some way.

Comment: This resolved my issue. I forgot I did hard code the absolute URL's for my development server in my theme's CSS file. I changed it to be the relative URL (/skin/frontend vs website/skin/frontend). Now works on both Staging and production server with no issues

Comment: Yeah, I've done it before :) Glad I could help